# Identifying individuals with observations across two datasets

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with R and ["WGCNA" package](http://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/). I am doing an integrative analysis of transcriptome and metabolome.

I have two `data.frames`, one for the transcriptome data: `datExprFemale`, and one for the metabomics data: `allTraits`, but I am having trouble merging the two `data.frames` together.

```
> datExprFemale[1:5, 1:5]
ID    gene1         gene2       gene3        gene4
F16 -0.450904880  0.90116800 -2.710879397  0.98942336
F17 -0.304889916  0.70307639 -0.245912838 -0.01089557
F18  0.001696330  0.43059153 -0.177277078 -0.24611398
F19 -0.005428231  0.32838938  0.001070509 -0.31351216
H1   0.183912553 -0.10357460  0.069589703  0.15791036

> allTraits[1:5, 1:5]
IND   met1          met2        met3         met4
F15   6546          68465       56465        6548
F17   89916         7639        2838         9557
F20   6330          53          7078         11398
F1    231           938         509          351216
```

The individuals in `allTraits` have measurements in `datExprFemale`, but some individuals in `datExprFemale` do not occur in `allTraits`.

Here is what I have tried to merge the two `data.frames` together:

```
# First get a vector containing the row names (individual's ID) in datExprFemale
IND=rownames(datExprFemale)
# Get the rows in which two variables have the same individuals
traitRows = match(allTraits$IND, IND)
datTraits = allTraits[traitRows, -1]
```

This gives me the following:

```
         met1                       met2    met3                      met4
11       0.0009                     0.0559   7.1224                    3.3894
12       0.0006                     0.0370  10.5776                   14.4437
15       0.0011                     0.0295   5.7941                   19.0225
16       0.0010                     0.0531   6.1010                    4.7698
17       0.0016                     0.0462   7.7819                    7.8796
19       0.0011                     0.0192  12.7126                    9.2564
20       0.0007                     0.0502   9.4147                   15.3579
21       0.0025                     0.0455   8.4129                   17.7273
NA           NA                         NA       NA                        NA
NA.1         NA                         NA       NA                        NA
NA.2         NA                         NA       NA                        NA
NA.3         NA                         NA       NA                        NA
NA.4         NA                         NA       NA                        NA
3        0.0017                     0.0375   8.8503                    8.7581
7        0.0006                     0.0156   7.9272                    4.9887
8        0.0011                     0.0154   8.4716                    8.6515
9        0.0010                     0.0306   9.1220                    3.5843
```

As you see there are some `NA` values, but I'm not sure why?

Now when I want to assign the ID of each individual to the corresponding row using the following code :

```
rownames(datTraits) = allTraits[traitRows, 1]
```

R gives this error:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names':
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong,

Comment: Do you want only the individuals who have metabolomics AND transcriptomic measurements?

Comment: Also `WGCNA` doesn't expect the two datasets to be merged (i.e. you typically run WGCNA on the expression data, then look for relationships with the modules it discovers and your metabolomic data)

Answer (score 5):

There's a few problems in your code:

1. In the format you've presented, your `datExprFemale` does not have `rownames`, so the match won't work at all.
2. `match` is telling you the which rows the individuals in `allTraits` correspond to in `datExprFemale`, not the rows you need to extract from `allTraits`.

Here's the approach I would take:

```
# First make sure `allTraits` and `datExprFemale` actually have the right rownames
rownames(datExprFemale) = datExprFemale$ID
rownames(allTraits) = allTraits$IND
# Now get the individuals who have both transcriptomic and metabolomic 
# measurements
has.both = union(rownames(allTraits), rownames(datExprFemale))
# Now pull out the subset of allTraits you want:
allTraits[has.both,]
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. in fact "datTraits" in the code must be like this:
       Insulin_ug_l Glucose_Insulin Leptin_pg_ml Adiponectin Aortic.lesions
F2_3            944      0.42055085     15148.76      14.339         296250
F2_14           632      0.67088608      6188.74      15.439         486313
F2_15          3326      0.16746843     18400.26      11.124         180750
F2_19           426      0.89671362      8438.70      16.842         113000
F2_20          2906      0.15691672     41801.54      13.498         166750
F2_23           920      0.58804348     24133.54      14.511         234000
F2_24          1895      0.24538259     52360.00      13.813         267500
F2_26          7293      0.09090909    126880.00      14.118         198000
F2_37           653      0.65849923     17100.00      12.470         121000
F2_42          1364      0.35703812     99220.00      14.531         110000

in which rows are individuals and columns are metabolites. this variable contains individuals who are in both transcriptomics and metabolomics files.
but in case of the codes I have copied them from the tutorial of WGCNA. 
thanks for any suggestion,
Behzad